cannot import GLTFLoader in threejs
VS code not allowing to type the import GLTFloader statement.
GLTF loader is installed in the same folder where the javascript file exists.
I am a beginner here.Please help me if you can.
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js
I tried typing this.

Details about the project (Are you using TypeScript? A bundler like Vite or Webpack? Dependencies?) are usually need to answer a question like this. You may have better luck posting (with a .zip of the project) on the threejs forums at https://discourse.threejs.org/. In the meantime you could try importing three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js instead, some bundlers require that (as of three.js r168).

You can instead load the GLTFLoader like this:
import {GLTFLoader} from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"

This way you don't have to download and manage the GLTF folder on your local device.
